# Where did the Finite Difference Coefficients come from?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

[Finite Difference Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) allows one to estimate various derivatives. My question is, where did they come from? How do you derive the finite difference coefficients?

Answer (score 3):

A more general (and numerically stable) way of deriving them is by means of Lagrange interpolation. Say that we are interested in the function $u(x)$ and that we have $n+1$ data values $x_j$, $j=0,1,\dots,n$. The Lagrange interpolating polynomial for $u(x)$ becomes
$$
p_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n L_j(x) u(x_j),
$$
where
$$
L_j(x) = \frac{\prod_{i\neq j} (x-x_i)}{\prod_{i\neq j}(x_j-x_i)}.
$$
Then, the $k$th derivative of $u(x)$ at, say $x=0$, is approximated by
$$
\frac{\text{d}^ku(x)}{\text{d}x^k}\Big|_{x=0} \approx \frac{\text{d}^k p_n(x)}{\text{d}x^k}\Big|_{x=0} = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{\text{d}^k L_j(x)}{\text{d}x^k}\Big|_{x=0} u(x_j) = \sum_{j=0}^n c_j^{(k)} u(x_j),
$$
where $c_k^{(j)}$ are the finite difference coefficients. Note that this holds for any grid distribution $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ so long as the points are distinct.

Comment: Hello @ekkilop !!! Could I ask you something about an elliptic problem? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31535/elliptic-problem

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients can be found by computing the Taylor Series for a function $f$ at several points (creating a [stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_(numerical_analysis))), then adding a linear combination of the approximations of the function together to get the desired quantity (typically a derivative) at a given point.

See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Derivation_from_Taylor.27s_polynomial) for more details