# Given derivative order and accuracy order, is there a general form of the central finite difference?

Tags: finite-differences

I'm trying to find a general formula for the central finite difference approximation given an nth order derivative with pth order accuracy.  I've looked up on Wikipedia, and their formula doesn't seem to work unless I'm reading it wrong (it also only works for the 2nd order accuracy).  I found a table of the coefficients on Wikipedia as well, but when I went to the referenced article I couldn't find the general form from which they derived the coefficients.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, but does anyone know the general form?

Comment: Maybe a link to the Wikipedia page would be helpful.

Comment: Finite Difference Coefficients:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient
Finite Difference "Formula":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Comment: The first answer to the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526059/where-did-the-finite-difference-coefficients-come-from/1526102#1526102
should give you a general idea of how to obtain formulas for any finite difference stencil.